# When device is connected internet, I can't get old messages- GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

While my device has not internet connection, I am sending message from server to application with GCM. After that, when device connect the internet, i can't get the message. Is it normal?

from http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html

"*If the device is not connected to GCM, the message will be stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules).* "

My messages have same collapse key; but still I have to get only 1 message when device is connected.

Comment: same collapse key means that you WILL GET ONLY 1 message: `if there is already a message with the same collapse key (and registration ID) stored and waiting for delivery, the old message will be discarded and the new message will take its place (that is, the old message will be collapsed by the new one)`

Comment: @Selvin I can't get this message, I already send only one message from server to application while not connected.

Comment: sry friend that is what google tells i havent migrated any c2dm to GCM yet so not so sure on this-- pls check when the net connection comes back google play is logged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get all the messages send to your device.

**GCM server keeps account of your all messages send to your device. And it shows these in notification area whenever device get connected to Internet.**

You are getting only one message because you are assigning same **NOTIFICATION ID** in **notify()** function of your code

your code probably using this :

```
        // 0 is notification id
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

change your **NOTIFICATION ID** everytime to get all messages in notification area.

Such As :

```
        static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

        if (NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824) {
            NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
        }
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);
```

if clause keeps you safe from overflow of int value. You can ignore it according to your requirement.

I have already tested this scenario. Now its your turn.
Happy to Help !!

Comment: May I know why this limit "1073741824", is it only because of integer limitations or any specific reason behind this

Comment: This is only the integer limit if you are running out with bulk of messages. You can remove this according to your application context.