# Battery Saving with Processes- GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If i have 3 apps that all use GCM, do all of them use same unified process? I mean 3 apps use 3 process to connect server without GCM, but by using GCM 3 apps use only 1 process, so it provides battery saving. Is it true?

Comment: yap for gcm connection to google play is used so a single process and each servers msg ll be pushed thus better battery lyf

Comment: thank you @droidhot Could you answer this question, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138569/when-device-is-connected-internet-i-cant-get-old-messages-gcm#comment16237274_12138569

Comment: You could use the ARO tool to find out how much power is being used and understand what sort of battery saving you are achieving. It allows you to profile the different processes https://developer.att.com/aro

Answer (score 1):

> I mean 3 apps use 3 process to connect server without GCM, but by using GCM 3 apps use only 1 process, so it provides battery saving. Is it true?

Not really. By "using GCM 3 apps use" 3 processes, but only while they are running. They use zero processes while they are not running. Yet they are still able to receive GCM messages, because there is another process, supplied by the operating system, that is responding to incoming GCM messages (among other things). The "battery saving" is not so much in having fewer processes, but in having a finely-tuned process managing socket states and able to receive messages even when the device fails over to mobile data (off of WiFi).

Comment: I can't understand "their is another process, supplied by the operating system" How can device get message without listening the port, is device check GCM server while application is not running? if it checks, how can use zero process?

Comment: @user1451549: sorry, I fixed the typo -- it should have been "there is another process, supplied by the operating system". The *apps' own processes* are not needed for the *device* to listen for GCM messages, because the *operating system* has *its own process* that runs all the time doing just that.