# GCM non-collapsible message always replaces the previous message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a non-collapse message via Google Cloud Messaging. For some reason a new message always replaces the previous one. I've tried to use different collapse-keys with no effect. Also omitting the collapse key does not work. What could be the problem?

This is an example code:

```
<?php
$ids[] = '<notification registration id of the test phone>';
sendNotification($ids, "test message 1", "key1");
sendNotification($ids, "test message 2", "key2");

function sendNotification($ids, $message, $collapseKey)
{
  $apiKey = '<api key here>';
  $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

  $data['title'] = 'AppName';
  $data['message'] = $message;

  $post['registration_ids'] = $ids;
  $post['data'] = $data;
  if ($collapseKey) {
    $post['collapse_key'] = $collapseKey;
  }

  $headers = array( 
      'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );
  $result = curl_exec( $ch );
  if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
  {
      echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
  }
  curl_close( $ch );

  echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: increment your message id

Comment: `mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());`

Comment: We are sending push notifications via the GCM HTTP Connection Server and I believe it's not possible to specificy a message id. @SorryForMyEnglish

Answer (score 0):

From the [GCM collapse key documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#collapsible), omitting the collapse-key should prevent replacing the old messages. Unless some of your messages already expired or your devices are not connected.

Also, the NOTIFICATION_ID with [notify method call](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) is implemented in your client application, not your service side code. So it should not be mattered if you are using HTTP server. You can refer to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-receive) about NOTIFICATION_ID in your client application's broadcast receiver. Also [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13640286/4195406) about how to generate unique NOTIFICATION_ID.

Comment: For some reason the old messages are always replaced. Example code added in the original question. @ztan

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question.

There are two scenarios:

For instance: you send two messages when your phone is offline (no wifi, no data, turned off)

1. Background/killed app - 
   I only get one notification, but actually i get the two data-message
2. Foreground -
   I get the two notification

Please remember not to add "collapse_key" parameter.

Hope this can help anyone else with the same problem.